# Is Mpeg Streaming supported in iOS/Mac?

Tags: ios, macos, streaming, video-streaming, mjpeg

I have a web application developed in ASP.Net which has provision to show live stream through a MJPEG Streaming server at same place. It is implemented as a service.

On Windows platforms it is working in IE, Chrome & Firefox, however it is not working in browsers on iOS/Mac platform.

I am not getting much help through google search so wanted to know if it is really supported by iOS/Mac. If yes then how can I do it.

Comment: May be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23157601/334402

Comment: I went through it but not able to conclude whether it is really supported or not. I found this link https://github.com/rodowi/Paparazzo.js useful but not sure if it is reliable & stable.